# Adding Microsoft Access Table to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ms-access, ole-db

I am looking to map gps coordinates from a Microsoft Access table (.mdb) in ArcMap. I successfully connected ArcMap to Microsoft Access through an OLE DB connection, and can see the Access table in both ArcCatalog and the Add Data dialog box. However, when I attempt to add the table I receive the following warning:

> A selected item could not be added to the map. General Function
>   Failure.

After searching online for a solution I thought maybe ArcMap could not read the file because of an incompatible driver. I am running Microsoft office 2016 (64-bit) on a 64-bit machine. However I read that since ArcGIS is a 32-bit program the correct driver for this setup would be Microsoft Office Access Database Engine 2007, which is the driver currently installed on my computer.

All other documentation I have found online indicates that this should be a fairly simple process, and I can not find any mention of the problem I am having.

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the new user [tour].  What is your ArcGIS version and what is the Access version of the actual MDB file (if you know it)?  Is it an MDB or an ACCDB?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.4, and the MDB file is Access 2000 file format.

Comment: Does the table you are trying to add have invalid field names? ArcGIS doesn't like special characters, spaces and reserved words in field names.

Comment: The field names are all alphanumeric, no spaces, and no reserved words are used. However, some of the fields are formatted as Boolean check box controls. I thought maybe this could be the issue because ArcMap does not offer Boolean data types. But I created a copy of my table, deleted the the Boolean type fields and tried again. Still no luck.

Comment: Do you want to try upgrading to an .accdb file rather than an .mdb. Or at a minimum Access 2002 - 2003 database (.mdb). I take it you can open the file using MsAccess 2016?